# how to change theme name in all files in wordpress ?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Can Anyone help me to change theme name in all files in WordPress and use my own theme name?
Remember i also want to change in theme name in functions also. 
I bought it from theme forest, i don't want my customer to know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is very hard and manual work to replace all instances of theme.

1. You can change only visible part of theme to minimize your work
   Name, Author, Theme URI etc
2. Replace all instances 
   Open your theme folder in SubLime editor and simply try to find theme name in theme folder then you can replace name as you per your requirement.